# Method security not working if I implement UserDetailsService in @Service

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've implemented Spring Security on my project. But method security annotations ignored if I implement UserDetailsService on @Service. 
What's wrong with this code?

```
@Transactional
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')")  /* it's ignored. */
    void update(UserEditForm form);

    @Override
    User loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
}

@Service
public class SimpleUserService implements UserService {
    // ommitted
}

@Transactional
public interface SomeService{

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')")  /* it's working fine */
    void doSomething();
}

@Service
public class SimpleSomeService implements SomeService {
    // ommitted
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    // ommitted
}
```

ps: Sorry I don't have well enough english knowledge.

Comment: You are trying to authorize before the user gets some role.

Comment: @Sam I don't understand. What you mean?

Comment: User will get his role when you will set the authentication object(you will do that in loadUserByUsername method),but in your case before that only you are calling that method...and dont use @preAuthorize in interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in SimpleUserService like this

```
@Service("simpleUserService")
public class SimpleUserService implements UserService {
    // ommitted
}
```

and in SecurityConfig, Autowire UserService with @Qualifier("simpleUserService")

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("simpleUserService")
 UserService userService;
```

Comment: Qualifier not needed because there is only one bean implemented UserDetailsService. Actually I'm talking about I want to use UserDetailsService and @Secured in same class.

Answer (score 0):

Do not annotate the interfaces with Spring annotations(`@Component`, `@Service`, `@Transactional`, `@Repository`), Add the annotations on the implementation classes.

Remove `@Transactional` on `UserService` interface, Create new class `UserServiceImpl` and add annotation `@Transactional`.

and also move the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')")` annotation on to the implementation method.

Comment: There is no difference. Actually it's not about that. It's about I can't use UserDetailsService with @Secured on same class